# ionic 2 caches data from http request - how to disable this?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Given this code:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.makeGetRequest();
}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
      this.myInput = '';
      this.http = http;
}

makeGetRequest() {
          this.http.get('https://domain.co/b2/words.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
              this.verbs = data;
              this.initializeItems();
          });
}
```

I load the data from the server, when the user is entering the screen. But the data is still the same on the device. What's my mistake?

Comment: "data from the server ... But the data is still the same on the device" - what does that mean? Where you are experiencing this undesired behavior?

Comment: Check if your server is answering with 304 Not Modified. In my experience, unless you have a huge payload, it makes no sense for you server to cache results, since the roundtrip will be almost as fast with the data or with the 304 response. That's mostly a server side question apparently.

Comment: Same Issue I have been faced. Any one solve that?